# Review queue audit question has wrong answer

Tags: discussion

In reviewing some PHP questions I came across an audit question regarding this question:

[How do I structure links on my page to access different sub directories?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36110354/best-php-navigation-method-with-sub-directories-in-mind)

The audit stipulates that this question has serious problems and should be closed. However reading over the question it is very clear to me. Looking at the question on the site the answers already existing on the question are exactly what I would expect the answer to be.

Can anyone explain then why I should be voting to close questions like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because people don't really pay attention.

The original close vote on that was for "too broad" - which I also disagree with. It's not broad. It's a very simple question, that probably has a duplicate somewhere because people ask about this *all the time*. But it's not broad.

That original close vote pushed it into the Close Votes review queue where it attracted the remaining four close votes needed - all primarily opinion based, and presumably people who didn't actually *read* the question to see it wasn't asking for opinions and just made a horrible use of the word "best" throughout the question.

It's been edited and reopened now.

Comment: That's why writing good title matters.

Comment: Thanks @animuson, I just wanted to make sure that I was doing the review process correctly.